# CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT (BSOD) happening on Windows 10 constantly

Tags: windows-10, freeze, bsod, sleep, gaming

I built this computer back in 2015 and it's been as powerful as it has been frustrating to maintain and constantly troubleshoot. I'm using it as a gaming PC, and lately it has started freezing then crashing to a BSOD with a "CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT". Anecdotally, it seems to happen after it has gone to sleep and then woken back up. However, restarting does not bypass this issue.

I can't specifically recreate it other than just playing a videogame for 15-20 minutes. It's not limited to a single game, either. When it freezes, I'll hold down the power button and restart the computer. Often it'll crash again on startup, but then load to the desktop after that (and then eventually freeze again).

Some more *(possibly red-herring clues)*:

- A few years ago I used OBS to record my gameplay and it would cause a freeze like this- however, at the time I had always restarted it not knowing it would eventually trip to a BSOD, so I can't say for sure it was a CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT. But it looked exactly the same as what's happening now.
- I stopped using OBS, but Nvidia GeForce has since introduced a feature that records gameplay. Even though I've disabled it, I have a hunch in the back of my mind that it could be the culprit.

If I just let Windows sit at the desktop (or do normal computer-related things), this problem will never happen- it appears to only be when gaming.

What I've done to troubleshoot this (this is the part where I complain about how awful Windows is):

- I've tried booting into Safe Mode, but apparently all the USB ports on my computer don't work on the screen where it asks what number I want (in order to finish booting into Safe Mode). My wired keyboard is completely unrecognized on this screen.
- I ran "sfc /scannow" and it found corrupted files, but could not fix, so I tried DISM but it could not find the source files... So a tutorial said to configure it in the Local Group Policy Editor, but apparently my computer doesn't have that...? *(May be a non-issue- see below*)*
- I just finished completely reformatting and reinstalling Windows 10 and I thought that solved the problem because the computer lasted for hours afterwords. However, after coming back to it (after it had gone to sleep) it froze and crashed just like before (15ish minutes into gaming).
- *I've since ran another "sfc /scannow" after re-installing Windows and this time it says it did not find any integrity violations.

Since I've reformatted, I'm certain my drivers are all up-to-date, but I'm open to other suggestions there. I *really* don't want to install third-party tools all willy-nilly unless it's absolutely necessary.

Any idea how to narrow this issue down? My complete guesses are that it's either Nvidia's software or something to do with Windows 10 sleep. If it's hardware, what parts are typical culprits?

I'll try to answer any follow-up questions as best as possible. My primary computer is a Mac, so admittedly I'm not very intuitive (or patient) with Windows. I'm trying to enjoy gaming as a stress-reliever, but instead it only spikes my stress levels.

Here are the specs of this PC:

- Intel Core i7-4790K
- Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD7 TH Motherboard
- Crucial Ballistix Sport 16GB RAM (2x8GB)
- Samsung 850 EVO SSD (x2)
- 3TB HDD
- Gigabyte GeForce GTX 970
- Corsair Carbide 500R Case
- Corsair 760 Power Supply

Edit: To add to it, I got a SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION the last time it froze/crashed to BSOD.

Edit 2: I re-flashed the BIOS, but the error still happens. I also tried disabling broadcasting in Steam just for good measure. Still no luck. I'll keep updating this as I try other things in case it could possibly help anyone else sometime.

Comment: I noticed Windows 10 also has "Game Mode" for recording, so I've tried disabling that, too, and we'll see if it has any impact.

Comment: Any chance you can temporarily put in another video card and see if the problem changes/goes away?

Comment: Unfortunately not unless I buy another one. I will keep this in mind to see if I might be able to get my hands on one to test.

Comment: Any available BIOS updates for your MB?

Comment: I'm not particularly well versed in updating BIOS, so I'll have to look into that. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Should be easy. Visit Gigabytes' website, put in model of your motherboard, and look in Downloads for the latest BIOS version. It should run like any other program from within Windows. Ez-peezy.

Comment: Awesome- thanks for that- what I read somewhere else was that I need to make some boot-drive and update from the BIOS itself (which concerned me with somehow messing it up).

Comment: That's more for cases where you don't have a working OS at the moment.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/ff557211(v=vs.85).aspx the CPU is deadlocked